# How to move packages and setup to a class

Tags: packages, document-classes

I am trying to prepare a latex format for a specific report that can be reused. I believe the best way to do this is a custom class that extends `article.cls`. What is the best way to move all the `\usepackage` commands and setup commands like `\captionsetup` to the class.

My preamble is as follows

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,csquotes,indentfirst,appendix}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false,format = hang,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[style = ieee, citestyle = ieee]{biblatex}
```

What can I do to move all of this to the class? I have tried using `\RequirePackage` but got the errors

> Command \quote already defined.
>   Command \abovecaptionskip already defined.
>   Command \belowcaptionskip already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to change anything: you can just put those lines in the class file. You could change `\usepackage` to `\RequirePackage` but they have identical definitions so it doesn't matter much which you use.

Comment: I ended up with several "Command already defined" errors stemming from article.cls

Comment: @kknight perhaps, but not from the commands shown. You can not expect answers to address answers in code you have not shown, or even mentioned. so presumably your class file is using `\LoadClass{article}` if it does that then changes things it has to use `\renewcommand` not `\newcommand` but that is unrelated to being in a class file, the same is true if you redefine things in the document preamble.